# Adding options to a select2 without changing its current state

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a `<select>` element with select2 loaded onto it. Afterwards, I make an ajax call to put values into the element, then call `$("#elem").trigger("change.select2")` to get the new `<option>`s to show up. If the user had been typing into the search box, this causes the dropdown to close and the search field to be emptied. What I want to do is to let the user continue typing without having to restart. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe not; that's a browser defined behavior and, in fact, different browsers and even different browser versions will behave diferrently when you add items to an open `<select>`.

As an alternative, you may try some select-like component, like [jQuery UI's Selectmenu](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) or [Select2](https://select2.github.io/); they're not real `<select>`'s, but actual custom JS components that behave like so. This should give you more control over the behavior.

Comment: I am already using Select2, would just like it to not reset everything the user did like opening the dropdown and typing in search text when it's updated with new options.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't pay attention to that small detail... The documentation gives no indication on how to do that, it would probably be necessary to study the source of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Read over the docs again and it seems like using `<select>` elements is basically equal to no dynamic data since everything is retrieved from the DOM, so the only way to get around this is to use an `<input>` element instead. The following code does what I want:

```
<input type="hidden" id="elem" />

var arr = [];

$("#elem").select2({
    data: { results: arr }
});

$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        arr = data;
    }
});
```

However this isn't a 100% answer in regards to using `<select>` instead, so I will leave this as unaccepted until (hopefully) a more relevant answer comes along.